# cuda shared memory overwrite?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to write a parallel prefix scan on cuda by following this [tutorial -](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html)

I am trying the work-inefficient 'double buffered one' as explained in the tutorial.

This is what I have:

```
// double buffered naive.

// d = number of iterations, N - size, and input.
__global__ void prefixsum(int* in, int d, int N)
{

        //get the block index
        int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

        // allocate shared memory
        extern __shared__ int temp_in[], temp_out[];

        // copy data to it.
        temp_in[idx] = in[idx];
        temp_out[idx] = 0;

        // block until all threads copy

        __syncthreads();

        int i = 1;
        for (i; i<=d; i++)
        {
                if (idx < N+1 && idx >= (int)pow(2.0f,(float)i-1))
                {
                        // copy new result to temp_out
                        temp_out[idx] += temp_in[idx - (int)pow(2.0f,(float)i-1)] + temp_in[idx];
                }
                else
                {
                        // if the element is to remain unchanged, copy the same thing
                        temp_out[idx] = temp_in[idx];
                }
                // block until all theads do this
                __syncthreads();
                // copy the result to temp_in for next iteration
                temp_in[idx] = temp_out[idx];
                // wait for all threads to do so
                __syncthreads();
        }

        //finally copy everything back to global memory
        in[idx] = temp_in[idx];
}
```

Can you point out what's wrong with this? I have written comments for what I think should happen.

This is the kernel invocation -

```
prefixsum<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_arr, log(SIZE)/log(2), N);
```

This is the grid and block allocations:

```
dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);
dim3 dimBlock(numThreadsPerBlock);
```

The problem is that I don't get the correct output for any input that's more than 8 elements long.

Comment: Can you add your kernel invocation? And what is the exact problem?

Comment: What is the values of `dimGrid` and `dimBlock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code

**Problem 1: extern shared memory**

Agh.... I hate `extern __shared__` memory. The problem is, that the compiler does not know how big are the arrays. As a result, they both point to the same piece of memory!
So, in your case: `temp_in[5]` and `temp_out[5]` refer to the same word in shared memory.

If you really want the `extern __shared__` memory, you can manually offset the second array, for example something like this:

```
size_t size = .... //the size of your array
extern __shared__ int memory[];
int* temp_in=memory;
int* temp_out=memory+size;
```

**Problem 2: Shared array index**

Shared memory is private for each block. That is, `temp[0]` in one block can be different than `temp[0]` in another block. However, you index it by `blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x` as if the temp arrays were shared between the blocks.

Instead, you should most likely index your temp arrays just by `threadIdx.x`.

Of course, the `idx` array is global and you index that one correctly.

Comment: You can add a third problem to that list if the target architecture is Fermi- the shared memory has not been declared `volatile`, which can lead correctness problems caused by compiler optimization

Comment: I don't see correctness problems as there are `__syncthreads()` barriers. Compiler will not optimize out shared memory in registers across these barriers.

Comment: Thanks CygnusX1, I didn't know all this about Shared Memory. I'll correct both of these and get back.